# COMBOBOX dinamica em C# (dados de tabela do BD SQL)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

Preciso carregar um combobox com os dados de uma tabela do SQL DEPARTAMENTO(com codigo e descrição/ a descrição é exibida no combobox mas o que é pego é o codigo)

Usei um dataSource (aquele configurado automaticamente clicando na > em cima do combobox(modo de edição gráfica)).

até ai perfeito:
Carrega perfeitamente os dados e passa direitinho o código mas ai vem meu problema:
Minha aplicação é composta de um form divido em dois (split.panel) de um lado tem a navegação e do outro alguns paineis sobrepostos um para cada tipo de cadastro etc...
Um destes paineis é o cadastro de DEPARTAMENTO, quando cadastro um departamento  e vou ao outro painel onde tem esse combobox esse novo departamento que eu cadastrei não aparece... Só os já cadastrados antes de eu abrir a aplicação aparecem. Se eu fechar minha aplicação e abrir de novo dai aparece tudo.

Pelo que andei pesquisando o datasource não tem isso que eu preciso (ele é 'estático'). Há outra forma de fazer isso? Nem precisa me postar todo o código se não quiserem (não tenho como mostrar meu código já feito pois estou no trabalho), podem me dizer só os recursos que devo utilizar ou um exemplo genérico.

Tentei usar o Combobox.Refresh(); mas não adiantou em nada.

Grata ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o código que utiliza para cadastrar um novo departamento dentro de um try catch, se não ocorrer nenhum erro pode adicionar o item salvo no combobox.

```
try
{
    Departamento departamento = new Departamento() { ID = 1, Nome = "Departamento" };
    //salvar departamento

    this.comboBox.Items.Add(departamento);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

**Uma outra solução é utilizar o método `Clear()` antes de preencher o combobox com os dados, dessa forma todos os itens serão removidos;**

```
this.comboBox.Items.Clear();
this.comboBox.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta mas eu queria algo "não gambi", digamos que eu resolva incrementar este programa e colocar a funcionalidade de deletar registros?! ai como vou atualizar o combobox? Terei que acrescentar o Item.Remove(não sei o comando) e se forem dois módulos (que são): mais um web?Duas pessoas (no minimo) inserido e removendo... Essa solução não é adequada... Eu preciso de algo que busque DIRETAMENTE DO BANCO e 'em tempo real' (pelo menos o mais atual até a combobox ser gerada)!

Comment: Certo, isso não é "gambi". Você poderia criar método que recebe um delegate para informar o método que dever ser executado depois de excluir/salvar um departamento. no caso, o método seria o mesmo que preenche o combobox com os dados do banco.

Comment: É muito mais natural e simplesmente consultar no banco e preencher a Combobox com esses dados, ficar adicionando linhas e excluido cada vez que for inserido/deletado algum departamento não é um raciocínio muito 'natural'. E eu não estava brincando quando falei gambiarra :) Acho que até encontrei a solução, testarei e se funcionar posto aqui pro resto do pessoal. Se tiver outra sugestões agradeço ^^

Comment: a lista de elementos tem o método Clear(), você pode utilizar isso antes de preencher todo o datasource. dessa forma ele sempre vai remover e adicionar tudo do banco.

Comment: Nossa!!! Vou testar isto com certeza. Coloque como resposta esse comentário ^^

Comment: Adicionei na descrição da mesma resposta, visto que são duas possíveis soluções :)

Answer (score 3):

Caso alguem tenha essa mesma dúvida, segue a função que fiz para carregar o combobox:

```
private void preencherCBDescricao()
        {
            String scon = "Data Source=NOME DO SERVIDOR\\BASESQL;Initial Catalog=SI_ATPS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=MINHASENHA";
            con = new SqlConnection(scon);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
            }
            String scom = "select * from departamento";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scom,con); 
            DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
            dtResultado.Clear();//o ponto mais importante (limpa a table antes de preenche-la)
            comboBox1.DataSource = null;
            da.Fill(dtResultado);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dtResultado;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "codigo";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "descricao";
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = "";
            comboBox1.Refresh(); //faz uma nova busca no BD para preencher os valores da cb de departamentos.
    }
```

Comment: Oi, Mariana, para nos comunicarmos usamos os comentários, perguntas e respostas devem focar na parte técnica. Você pode marcar a resposta do Italo como correta, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)

Comment: Obrigada, sou nova e não sabia! Vou cuidar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,
Estava passando por um problema desses no meu projeto acadêmico, com as respostas da qui e da li consegui fazer o que realmente queria.

Usando C# com SQLServer

O projeto é em POO, então segue a classe e botoes

```
    // aqui é o Evento do botão Clicar do comboBox
    private void cmbCategoria_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        CategoriaNegocio catNegocio = new CategoriaNegocio();
        List<Categoria> categoria = catNegocio.ListarCategoriasCombo();

        /* 
          OBS: NA PROPRIEDADE cmbCategoria DataBindings o Text tem que estar (none)
          DataSource (o que vai ser carregado) --> Aqui esta pegando a Lista de categorias, preenchidas 
          com o select do  método ListarCategoriasCombo
          DisplayMember = "nomeCategoria" -->  o campo que vai carregar da tablea (exibir no combo) tem que ser igual ao do SQL
          cmbCategoria.ValueMember --> o valor que vai retornar pra programacao
          SelectedValue = "idProduto"  --> gravar na FK da tabela Produto, e passa para o produto (inserir)           
         */

        this.cmbCategoria.DataSource = categoria;
        this.cmbCategoria.DisplayMember = "nomeCategoria";
        this.cmbCategoria.ValueMember = "idCategoria";
        this.cmbCategoria.SelectedValue = "idProduto";

    }



   // metodo que retorna uma lista de categorias do SQL com uma "tabela" usando o filtro        
    public List<Categoria> ListarCategoriasCombo()
    {

       // select que vai ao banco e retorna a consulta já ordenada
        string _SQL = @"select 
                        idCategoria,nomeCategoria
                        from Categoria
                        order by nomeCategoria";
        //mandar instrucoes ao sql  (Command)
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = clsConexao.Conectar();
        cmd.CommandText = _SQL;
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<Categoria> categorias = new List<Categoria>();
        // quando acabar as linhas que retornou da consulta, sai do While
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Categoria cat = new Categoria();
            cat.idCategoria = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("idCategoria"));
            cat.nomeCategoria = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("nomeCategoria"));
            categorias.Add(cat);
        }

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

        return categorias;

    }




  // objeto transferencia onde preencho o Objeto
  public class Categoria
  {
    public int idCategoria { get; set; } 
    public string nomeCategoria { get; set; }
    public string descCategoria { get; set; }

  }
```

Espero ter contribuído =D